# MS ADO DLL not properly installed?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ado, visual-studio-2010

I'm just trying to install everything needed to start messing with ADO in MSVC 2010 Express just to learn more about it and I may end up using some of these things I learn at work.

I have read from MSDN that I need to install MDAC, so I went and got the latest version here:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793

From what I've read online I need to use the #import pre-compiler directive with the name of my MS ADO DLL ("msado15.dll" is mentionned) to initialize ADO in MSVC but it seems that even after installing MDAC I do not have this DLL. What have I done wrong ?

I am using Windows 7 64 if that matters.

Comment: You already had it, it comes pre-installed with Windows.  Hopefully you didn't mess things up too much.  What you read is *very* dated, there have been at least 6 major releases since then.  And a really heavy one at Win7 SP1 that broke backwards compatibility.  Anyhoo, c:\program files (x86)\common files\system\ado directory.  Nobody writes this kind of code in C++ anymore.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I didn't do my homework. I'm very new to this.

Comment: If you need to repair mdac, you can look for mdac.inf file, right click, and choose install. Then, it may need the windows cd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"ADO" is the old COM/ActiveX "Data Object" component.

The newer/bigger/brighter object model is "ADO.Net", for C# and VB.Net.

The link you referenced clearly refers to the old ADO:

> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793
>
> Supported operating systems: Windows 2000, Windows 98, Windows ME,
>   Windows NT

Soooooooo:

1) Start out with this link:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ctka9db.aspx

2) You *should* have everything you need by virtue of having Windows 7 (Pro?) and having installed MSVS 2010 Express.

3) Here is a good example of using ADO.Net in managed C++:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1078/Using-ADO-NET-in-a-managed-C-application

'Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. I will rate after I test everything !